# Paste Not Working First Time on CkEditor on Edge Browser

Tags: clipboard, microsoft-edge, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to paste a text on CkEditor but it's not working. Neither CTRL+V Nor Right Click & paste works. This is happening on the very first time when application loads and once it loads and if I try again copying and pasting it then works i.e. on second attempt of copy & paste it's working fine!

Also, the right click and paste is enabled for the first time and once paste is selected then nothing happens and paste also becomes disabled also the copied text somehow disappears from clipboard and it's not there anymore so can't paste anywhere else also!

Ironically the same thing is working fine on Chrome but it's not on Edge Browser(Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134)

Tried browsing online but out of luck yet as similar issues were raised with CkEditor but fixed past 4.2 version and I'm using Version 4.9

Any leads would be appreciated!

Comment: I try to make a test with CKEditor 4 on their site with the same version of MS Edge. Based on my testing, I find that i cannot use right click paste option but CTRL + V is working fine on my side. So I can paste the text without any issue. It also show me a message,'Your browser doesn‘t support pasting with the toolbar button or context menu option.' Beside that CKEditor has this issue so you can try to provide your feedback on their site regarding this issue. I also find that this issue is only with CKEditor 4 version. Options for paste working fine with CKEditor 5 version.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I already raised an issue in github for the same and waiting for their reply.

Comment: Thank you for let us know about that, If possible than you can try to post the link of that thread which you posted on github.

Comment: Here is the link for Github issue raised
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-sdk/issues/282

Comment: Guys, I'm really getting lost into this. Can anyone advise how can I overcome this issue!

Comment: As this issue caused by CK Editor. We cannot correct it from our end using any option or any code. If possible than you can try to use CKEditor 5 version to avoid this issue.